# Spread an array of components in render in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently render an array of component as child of another component like this:

```js
const myComponents = [
  <div key='1'>Component 1</div>,
  <div key='2'>Component 2</div>,
  <div key='3'>Component 3</div>,
];

render() {
  return (
    <AnotherComponent>
      {myComponents}
      <div>Another element</div>
    </ AnotherComponent>
  )
}
```

My issue is that inside `AnotherComponent`, my array of components is rendered as an array (which makes sense):

```js
// Inside AnotherComponent
console.log(this.props.children) // [[ {}, {}, {} ], {} ]
```

My expected output is that components should be "spread", like this:

```js
// Inside AnotherComponent
console.log(this.props.children) // [ {}, {}, {}, {} ]
```

I have tried to `map` the components in the render but the output is the same:

```js
const myComponents = [
  ...
];

render() {
  return (
    <AnotherComponent>
      {myComponents.map(component => component)}
      <div>Another element</div>
    </ AnotherComponent>
  )
}
```

I can achieve that with flattening my array of children inside `AnotherComponent`. But I was wondering if there was a syntax that would allow me to flatten it before, so that `AnotherComponent` is cleaner.

Reason I want to achieve this is because I do some complex layout rendering inside `AnotherComponent`. This requires the children not to be arrays, unless I explicitly want it, which is not the case here.

Edit: Here is a demo with my current output and my expected output:

```js
const components = [
  <div>Component 1</div>,
  <div>Component 2</div>,
  <div>Component 3</div>,
];

const MyLayoutComponent = ({ children }) => {
  console.log('❌ Current output', children);
  console.log('✅ Expected output', children.flat());
  return <div>{children}</div>
}

const App = () => (
  <MyLayoutComponent>
    {components}
    <div>Some other component</div>
  </MyLayoutComponent>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine as the expected output. Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this to show the issue happening.

Comment: I edited with a demo of the issue

Comment: Even in your demo, the children is an array and not an array of arrays

Comment: Sorry, I made the example too minimal so the problem was not visible. If I have other elements rendered you can see that the arrary is rendered as an array

Comment: Why is it a problem that the children are in an array? They still render correctly: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-question-61474340-2-cpds7 It's **really** common for children to look like that, basically every list you've ever done, etc. :-) And it's important for React, so it knows they're a list and can optimize re-rendering using the keys.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, I am not used tot stack snippets, it's done now :)

Comment: *"it's done now"* Great stuff! :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It is a problem because I have a complex layout system in this component, that does some magic with the children. In this minimal example it does not change anything in the render, but within the system I have it is an issue. I could change the system or flatten the children, but I would prefer to solve the issue beforehand if possible :)

Comment: @neiya - Without knowing the specifics, my instinct would be to use `flat` when doing the rendering to flatten a single layer (not the full depth), But again, I don't know the specifics. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that they come through as an array is appropriate, and useful because React can optimize re-rendering if the order of the list changes based on the `key` attribute. It's the fact they're in an array that makes React look for a key.

If you don't want them to be a list, per se, you could use a fragment instead:

```
const myComponents = <>
  <div>Component 1</div>
  <div>Component 2</div>
  <div>Component 3</div>
</>;
```

That will still come through as a single entry in `props.children`, but that entry will be a fragment, not an array, and React won't require keys on it, etc.

The only other answers I can think of are to put your other components in an array as well (but that will require they have a `key`):

```
const App = () => (
  <MyLayoutComponent>
    {[...components, <div key="other">Some other component</div>]}
  </MyLayoutComponent>
);
```

```js
const components = [
  <div>Component 1</div>,
  <div>Component 2</div>,
  <div>Component 3</div>,
];

const MyLayoutComponent = ({ children }) => {
  console.log('✅ Current child count', children.length);
  console.log('✅ Expected child count', children.flat().length);
  return <div>{children}</div>
}

const App = () => (
  <MyLayoutComponent>
    {[...components, <div key="other">Some other component</div>]}
  </MyLayoutComponent>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Or to ditch JSX for this one case and write the `createElement` call directly:

```
const App = () => React.createElement(
  MyLayoutComponent,
  {
    children: [
      ...components,
      <div>Some other component</div>
    ]
  }
);
```

```js
const components = [
  <div>Component 1</div>,
  <div>Component 2</div>,
  <div>Component 3</div>,
];

const MyLayoutComponent = ({ children }) => {
  console.log('✅ Current child count', children.length);
  console.log('✅ Expected child count', children.flat().length);
  return <div>{children}</div>
}

const App = () => React.createElement(
  MyLayoutComponent,
  {
    children: [
      ...components,
      <div>Some other component</div>
    ]
  }
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I can't think of a JSX way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! The fact that react can optimize re-rendering when it's an array is something I have not thought of and that is important.

Comment: @neiya - Happy to help! I think that bit about array rendeiring optimization is only useful if the array gets reordered, or entries are removed, or entries are inserted, but still... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try concat() method.

```
const App = () => (
  <MyLayoutComponent>
    {components.concat(<div>Some other component</div>)}
  </MyLayoutComponent>
);
```

It will concat your array with other component.

[image]